# List into json format using Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a list like below...

```
lst = ['dosa','idly','sambar']
```

i need to convert the above data to below format by using Python.

```
[{'menuitem': 'idly'},
 {'menuitem': 'dosa'},
 {'menuitem': 'sambar'},
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), make a list of dictionaries:

```
>>> lst = ['dosa','idly','sambar']
>>> [{'menuitem': x} for x in lst]
[{'menuitem': 'dosa'}, {'menuitem': 'idly'}, {'menuitem': 'sambar'}]
```

Then, convert it to json using [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([{'menuitem': x} for x in lst])
'[{"menuitem": "dosa"}, {"menuitem": "idly"}, {"menuitem": "sambar"}]'
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Although I expect pro  don't just solve the questions

Comment: Its Working Good.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = ['dosa','idly','sambar']
x="menuitem"
print map(lambda i:{x:i},lst)
```

Output:
`[{'menuitem': 'dosa'}, {'menuitem': 'idly'}, {'menuitem': 'sambar'}]`